# How to pass parameters to Crystal reports?

Tags: vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports-2010

I am trying to filter customers using a parameter in Crystal, by typing a customer code in a `textbox`. I created a parameter for the customer code, and tried to pass it's value using the code shown below, but it is not working. When I click on the button it is showing all customers not only the filtered ones:

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class ParametroCrForm

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim relatorio As New ReportDocument

        relatorio.Load("C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Crystal.Estudo\Crystal.Estudo\CrystalReport1.rpt")

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        If codigoTextBox.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Digite um c�digo de cliente", "Aten��o", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = codigoTextBox.Text
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = relatorio.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("codigoParametro")
        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = relatorio
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you create a selection formula in your report based on that parameter?

Comment: No, I haven't I am really new in codding, I didn' know about that additional step, It worked!! Thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to explanation from ABZY, I had to add selection formula in my report.

In the link below it is explained how to do that:

http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_parameter_string.htm

Thanks again Abzy!!